# Square root in expression trees

Tags: parsing, binary-tree, expression-trees

Normally in expression trees we have binary operators like +,-,/,* in the non leaf nodes and the values in the leaf nodes.

How is a square root represented within an expression tree? Consider the following expression:

```
sqrt(a) + b^2 + c*2 + d
```

How will this be evaluated in an expression tree? I was asked this question in a job interview.

Answer (score 2):

Square root is a unary operator.
It has one parent and one leaf.

Comment: What if its an Nth root? Would N go in the left child and whatever is under the root into the right child?

Answer (score 0):

```
sqrt(a) + b^2 + c*2 + d
```

Here, square root acts as a `unary` operator and, thus, will be the parent node for the leaf node containing `a`.